# Ambari Server fails to start because of missing stack definitions

Tags: hadoop, ambari

II successfully built the Apache Ambari from git repository, installed and configured the ambari-server. But it just won't start. In the log is the following error:

```
 Error injecting constructor, org.apache.ambari.server.AmbariException: Unable to 

find stack definitions under stackRoot = /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks
  at org.apache.ambari.server.stack.StackManager.<init>(StackManager.java:149)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.stack.StackManager annotated with @com.google.inject.internal.UniqueAnnotations$Internal(value=1)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.AmbariMetaInfo.init(AmbariMetaInfo.java:272)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.AmbariMetaInfo.class(AmbariMetaInfo.java:131)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.AmbariMetaInfo
    for field at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.ambariMetaInfo(AmbariServer.java:180)
  at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer.class(AmbariServer.java:180)
  while locating org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Ambari doesn't come with Stacks for installing any components. You might want to look at Apache BigTop stack, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it running now at least ambari server, but not the stack.
Thank you for the hint.